# Flow: how to get deleted item values?

Tags: sharepoint-online, workflow, list-item, delete, flow

I need to make some updates to a list based on the data deleted in another list. I tried using 'When an item is deleted' trigger but when I try to get the data in the column which was just deleted I can only find the following in dynamic content.

[image]

I am guessing flow somehow does not provide this data. But then what use is knowing the deleted time if I can't do anything based on the data that just got deleted?

Anyone know any workarounds for this?

Answer (score 0):

The only workaround I found was adding ParentID column to child lists.

I have a flow that creates and updates items in child lists when an item is created or updated in parent list. This flow keeps ParentID field updated with item ID from parent list.

A second flow triggers when an item is deleted in parent list, searches for item ID in child lists' ParentID column and deletes those items.