# How i can get a custom column value for a deleted item inside my "When an item is Delete" flow

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, power-automate, flow, power-platform

I have a custom list named "Customer code", with those values:

[image]

Now I define an automated workflow >> which runs when an item is deleted. but inside this workflow how I can get the FormID value? currently those are the only values available for us when an item get deleted inside the power automate flow:

```
body":{"ID":106,"Name":"h1","FileNameWithExtension":"h1","DeletedByUserName":"******","TimeDeleted":"2023-03-31T16:50:32Z","IsFolder":false}}
```

Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known issue/limitation with **When an item is deleted** trigger in Power automate flows.

When the flow runs, item is already deleted from SharePoint list so it only returns basic properties like below:

[image]

Check similar threads at:

1. [Power Automate delete trigger does not bring custom columns](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/304523/power-automate-delete-trigger-does-not-bring-custom-columns)
2. [Flow: how to get deleted item values?](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/241299/flow-how-to-get-deleted-item-values)
3. [Flow Assistance: When an item is deleted](https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/General-Power-Automate/Flow-Assistance-When-an-item-is-deleted/td-p/426098)